# Error while sending email using Sendgrid and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I'm sending emails with Sendgrid and NodeJS but got the following error:

```
D:\NodejsCODE\email_app\app.js:19
from_email = new helper.Email("test@example.com")
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Email' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\NodejsCODE\email_app\app.js:19:24)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

And the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var config = require('./config');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
app.set('my_api_key', config.access_key);
var helper = require('sendgrid').mail

from_email = new helper.Email("test@example.com")
to_email = new helper.Email("rahilansari261@gmail.com")
subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
content = new helper.Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js")
mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)

var sg = require('sendgrid')(my_api_key);
var request = sg.emptyRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/v3/mail/send',
  body: mail.toJSON()
});

sg.API(request, function(error, response) {
  console.log(response.statusCode)
  console.log(response.body)
  console.log(response.headers)
})
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

var port            =       process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// console.log("hlo");
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic Happens @ http://localhost:' + port);
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I tried your code with sendgrid@4.7.1, node v6.2.1

Comment: so what happened..... Is it working on your machine and i have sendgrid@4.7.1, node v6.9.1

Comment: yeah, it works, I don't get any errors.

Comment: Then I think problem is in key what you say

Comment: I'll put the code I used in an answer maybe you can look at that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the following code and seems to work OK.  No error on the line you stated.  Maybe an issue with your setup?

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');





var app = express();
app.set('my_api_key', 'key');
var helper = require('sendgrid').mail

from_email = new helper.Email("test@example.com")
to_email = new helper.Email("rahilansari261@gmail.com")
subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
content = new helper.Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js")
mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)

var sg = require('sendgrid')(my_api_key);
var request = sg.emptyRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/v3/mail/send',
  body: mail.toJSON()
});

sg.API(request, function(error, response) {
  console.log(response.statusCode)
  console.log(response.body)
  console.log(response.headers)
})
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

var port            =       process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// console.log("hlo");






// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic Happens @ http://localhost:' + port);
module.exports = app;
```